# C++ Downcasting with virtual base class

Tags: c++, oop

I've defined my project with interfaces like the following:

```
class iA
class iB : virtual public iA
class iC : virtual public iA
```

When I implement the interfaces now..

```
class A : virtual public iA
class B : virtual public iB, public A
class C : virtual public iC, public A
```

Thanks to virtual, I do not suffer under the diamond inheritance problem. But now, I want to downcast a pointer to iA to the type A.

```
void func1(iA* a){
    static_cast<A*>(a);
}
```

This isn't possible because A virtual inherits from `iA`. I could remove the `virtual` keyword at the class `A`, but then I would suffer on the diamond inheritance problem.
I know I could use `dynamic_cast` to cast `iA` to `A`, but I really DON'T wanna do this.

The situation where I have to cast this way is the following:
The interface iA defines a function `doSomething(iA* a)`. I implement this function in class `A`. Inside the function I need some members of `A` (which are not members of `iA`), so I have to cast `iA*` a to `A*`. This cast is safe, since I know that `iA*` is an object of type `A` because the implementation was used in which `A`, `B` and `C` exist (otherwise, the function `doSomething()` would never have been called in class `A`).

Is this a bad design? How could I improve this design to avoid the need of `dynamic_cast`?

Greetings

Comment: it's hard to say how to improve the design without knowing the details. it's possible that it needs redesign.

Comment: This sure looks like a bad design to me.  Impossible to say what a good design would be without knowing what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After introducing interfaces you can not assume a class implementing iA is an A (it might be any of some possible [A0, A1, ... An].

Leaving you two options:

- Drop interfaces
- Use dynamic_cast